# Name that ...Name? 10

Tags: riddle, knowledge

> *A rip takes the first of my vocal surname
>
>   You'll see me as a rival because of where I came
>
>   One of two things to a saint born in Rome no surprise
>
>   Take half of this riddle's series for an opposite prize*

Name the name.

Hint 1:

> The second line refers to the name itself, not of any famous person with the name. Also, don't stress over the fourth line, it's an in-series reference to these riddles

Hint 2:

> This name is of Italian origin

Hint 3:

> Depending on how you say this name, it might sound like 2 names combined. Also the name is feminine by the way

That's about all the hints I can give without being too easy with them.

Hint 4:

> I thought of another hint to push you in the right direction. The second line refers to how the name itself means "rival"

Comment: I love these puzzles! $\color{darkorange}{\bigstar}$

Comment: I have reached my daily voting limit, so I cannot upvote... but I only need to wait $7$ more minutes :D

Comment: I like @user477343 - always giving upvotes, favorites, and compliments!

Comment: Is the name italian or latin?

Comment: The name is Italian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stealing this from @tox123...

> Emiliana

A rip takes the first of my vocal surname

> Emilíana Torrini is a singer, Rip Torn's surname has the same first part

You'll see me as a rival because of where I came

> The name comes from Latin aemulus (rival)

One of two things to a saint born in Rome no surprise

> [Trasilla and Emiliana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trasilla_and_Emiliana) were aunts of St. Gregory, who was born in Rome

Hint: *Depending on how you say this name, it might sound like 2 names combined.*

> Emily Anna

Comment: YES!!!!!!! You pulled it off!

Comment: If you want to expand, the fourth line refers to the solution of Name that Name 5.

Comment: Good job, I'm so jealous though.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if any of these clues are correct, but are you

> Mark?

A rip takes the first of my vocal surname

> Vocal surname...could refer to Mark Wahlberg?

You'll see me as a rival because of where I came

> One definition of the word "mark" is "a target".

One of two things to a saint born in Rome no surprise

> This could refer to Pope Saint Mark, born in Rome and became Pope in the 4th century (I'm not talking about the original Saint Mark here).

Take half of this riddle's series for an opposite prize

> No idea, but you said not to worry about this.

Comment: No, it isn't Mark

Answer (score 1):

> Emilia

A rip takes the first of my vocal surname

> No clue. Possibly em-dash or something. "Rip 'em" seems to be a phrase

You'll see me as a rival because of where I came

> Emilia is Italian for rival

One of two things to a saint born in Rome no surprise

> Emmelia of Caesarea gave birth to not one, but two saints.

As for the fourth hint I haven't been following the series closely so I can't say.
I also don't know how you say it as two names, I've only ever heard one related name.

Comment: Ohhh... you are so close!!!

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess based on some of the extra hints you added:

> Rosaria?

because

> A saint born in Rome should be familiar with a rosary.

and from the hints you added:

> The name is feminine and I think Italian and if you pronounce Rosaria as Rose-aria, you say it as two names.

However, I can't make any sense out of the first 2 lines of the riddle...

Comment: It isn't Rosaria

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a wild stab and say:

> Franscesca

A rip takes the first of my vocal surname

> Frrrr kinda sounds like paper tearing?

You'll see me as a rival because of where I came

> Franscesca is Latin for French-woman, the French (Gauls or Germanic tribe) being enemies of the Romans then again, who wasn't an enemy of the Romans.

One of two things to a saint born in Rome no surprise

> Franscesca of Rome is a saint

As for the fourth hint I haven't been following the series closely so I can't say.

Comment: No, it isn't Francesca

Comment: Also, the second line is the meaning of the name itself, as in, the name legit means "rival"

Comment: @XavierStanton thanks, most useful hint yet. Also, if I make a new answer should I edit this one or write a new one?

Comment: Whichever is easier for you